# how to increment and decrement product quantity?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to increment and decrement more product quantity in cart and also I want to show current value in span tag.

```
<a href="javascript:" id="minus2" onclick="decrementValue()"/><strong>-</strong></a>
<input type="text" id="qty2" name="<?php echo $s?>" min="1" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>">

<a href="javascript:" id="add2" onclick="incrementValue()"/><strong>+</strong></a>
&nbsp;<a href="cart-item-delete.php?cartdetailsID=<?php echo $cartdetailsID; ?>"><i class="icon-trash icon-large" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete cart?');" ></i> </a>
<?php if($free_qty!=0){ echo "<br>".$free_qty." Free";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code to increment and decrements quantity into qty textbox.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

    $quantity = 3;
    $cartdetailsID = 1;
    $free_qty = 1;   
?>

<a href="javascript:" id="minus2" onclick="decrementValue()"/><strong>-</strong></a>
<input type="text" id="qty2" name="<?php echo $s?>" min="1" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>">

<a href="javascript:" id="add2" onclick="incrementValue()"/><strong>+</strong></a>
&nbsp;<a href="cart-item-delete.php?cartdetailsID=<?php echo $cartdetailsID; ?>"><i class="icon-trash icon-large" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete cart?');" ></i> </a>
<?php if($free_qty!=0){ echo "<br>".$free_qty." Free";} ?>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var qty2 = document.getElementById("qty2");
    function decrementValue(){

         if(!isNaN(qty2.value) && qty2.value > 0 ) {

             qty2.value--;

         }

    }

    function incrementValue(){

         if(!isNaN(qty2.value)) {

             qty2.value++;

         }

    }

</script>


</body>
</html>
```